# Multiple ValueSelector for one MoveSelector

Tags: optaplanner

How can i set multiple value selectors for one move selector in Optaplanner? the documentation says clearly that: "A MoveSelector is often composed out of EntitySelectors, **ValueSelectors** or even other MoveSelectors, which can be configured individually if desired", which i assume means multiple value selectors can be assigned to one move selector, which makes sense to me, however i get an unmarshalling error when trying that.

```
<unionMoveSelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>com.rdthree.plenty.domain.activity.Activity</entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>startTime</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>endTime</variableName>
            </valueSelector> <--this is the line where the error stems from
            <filterClass>myclass(don't want to say the name of it)</filterClass>
        </changeMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalling of solverConfigResource (activitySolverConfig.xml) fails.
```

cause:

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: Duplicate field valueSelectorConfig
---- Debugging information ----
field               : valueSelectorConfig
class               : org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelectorConfig
required-type       : org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMoveSelectorConfig
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 36
class[1]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelectorConfig
class[2]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig
class[3]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
```

i'm not copying the entire error text but i can assure you it's referring to the fact that i have two value selectors.

Answer (score 0):

A `changeMoveSelector` can only have 1 `valueSelector` currently.

I presume you want a cartesian product (otherwise you can use a `unionMoveSelector`) over those 2 `changeMoveSelector`s, so:

```
  <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <entitySelector id="cartesianProductEntitySelector"/>>
      <valueSelector>
        <variableName>startTime</variableName>
      </valueSelector>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="cartesianProductEntitySelector"/>
      <valueSelector>
        <variableName>endTime</variableName>
      </valueSelector>
    </changeMoveSelector>
  </cartesianProductMoveSelector>
```

This means that a single move (a CompositeMove) changes both the startTime and the endTime of 1 (and the same) entity. See docs section about `cartesianProductMoveSelector` and mimic selection for more info.

Note that this `cartesianProductMoveSelector` can be nested in a `unionMoveSelector` if desired to union those `CompositeMove`s with other moves.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. I see that you are guy for optaPlanner. I just wanted to say that there are javadocs missing for a lot of the methods in the API, do you think that will be fixed in a further version?

Comment: yes, I am working on making sure that all classes in `org.optaplanner.core.api` are fully javadocced (most are).

Comment: This produces `Multiple EntityMimicRecorders (usually EntitySelectors) have the same id (cartesianProductEntitySelector).`